# How can I limit ListBucket results with an IAM policy to list spcific folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket with several folders/subfolders and I am using CloudBerry Drive to present the storage to users in Windows Explorer.  For confidentiality reasons, I need to create an IAM policy that will limit the results shown in the `s3:ListBucket` operation by default - with project specific policies that will reveal specified folders when that policy is attached to the IAM account.

I have tried to use the prefix option (see code block) without success but the documentation I have found suggests this should work.  Perhaps I have misunderstood the prefix option?

Here is an example of the S3 structure:

```
arn:aws-cn:s3:::mybucket

projects/
projects/confidential/
projects/my project/
projects/public/
```

I need a default policy that will only return projects/public when I list the content of the projects/ folder in Explorer.  I then need to be able to add a policy to selected IAM accounts that would also list projects/my project when I list the content of the projects/ folder.

```
{
   "Action": ["s3:GetBucketLocation","s3:ListBucket"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws-cn:s3:::mybucket"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": ["","projects/public/*"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": ["/"]
                }
            }
        }
```

So far, using various combinations of prefix, I can either list nothing at all, or everything - I just can't seem to limit what is returned.  Is this even possible?

If not - are there any alternative approaches to achieve the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "limit what is returned", but you can limit "what is requested".

That is, you can `Allow` a request where the Prefix is `projects/public`. Requests that do *not* have this prefix will then be Denied by default.

The difficulty is that users will not be able to "navigate" from the root of the bucket to the allowed prefix. They will need go **go directory to the prefix** to be able to list objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification John,

So in my case, the Cloudberry client would need to send a request which included the prefix - which obviously can not happen in a directory browsing scenario.  Back to the drawing board.

Regards.